# Как реализовать flex-direction: column; без выставления высоты элементам?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть таблица, где количество строк может быть в любом количестве.
Как подобное можно сделать при условии динамической высоты?

PS. Порядок размещения строк должен остаться таким же.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tbody {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  outline: 1px solid #a52a2a;
  height: 150px;
}

tr {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid #a52a2a;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Пункт 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Пункт 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Пункт 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Пункт 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Пункт 5</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что именно вы хотите сделать? Чем вас не устраивает то, что есть сейчас?

Comment: `flex` и таблицы, это что-то новенькое

Comment: В битриксе все не по людски. Мне там надо порядок строк сверху вниз сделать.

Comment: Без указания фиксированного или максимального значения высоты - никак.

Comment: Понял, только в топку флекс. Спасибо.